# Android debug from another device

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

Is there a way to connect two Android Phones so that one phone can debug an app ,edit fields and run code. So that one Phone attaches a Debugger on the other Phone?
(The Phone that should be debugged has Android 6.0 and the other one can either be 4.2.2 or 5.1)

Comment: On the same way that you build single phone on your pc .connect 2-3 or mora device at the same time and when you want to debug then select all  your devices .

Comment: I mean to debug without a Computer/Laptop, only the two Phones(and a Network connection)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way... !
No one Phone can act as a Compiler/Debugger for another phone. 
But you can report...!!

Comment: What do you mean by "report"

Comment: See this link: http://support.blackberry.com/kb/articleDetail?articleNumber=000032516

Comment: Are there stacktraces anywhere in the report files?